# Using different jquery dialog form in the same page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use more than one JQuery dialog form in the same page. One of them work (divEditPeriod) the other doesn't. What am I doing wrong? code bellow:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#divEditPage").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        minHeight: 20,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        resizable: false,
        open: function(event, ui) {
         $(this).parent().appendTo("#divEditPageDlgContainer");
        },
       });

       $("#divEditPeriod").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        minHeight: 20,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        resizable: false,
        open: function(event, ui) {
         $(this).parent().appendTo("#divEditPeriodDlgContainer");
        },
       });

      });

      function closeDialog(Form) {
       //Could cause an infinite loop because of "on close handling"
       $(Form).dialog('close');
      }

      function openDialog(title, linkID, Form) {

       var pos = $("#" + linkID).position();
       var top = pos.top;
       var left = pos.left + $("#" + linkID).width() + 10;


       $(Form).dialog("option", "title", title);
       $(Form).dialog("option", "position", [left, top]);   
       $(Form).dialog('open');
      }



      function openDialogAndBlock(title, linkID, Form) {
       openDialog(title, linkID, Form);

       //block it to clean out the data
       $(Form).block({
        message: '<img src="<%=ResolveUrl("~") %>images/async.gif" />',
        css: { border: '0px' },
        fadeIn: 0,
        //fadeOut: 0,
        overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', opacity: 1 } 
       });
      }        

      function unblockDialog(Form) {
       $(Form).unblock();
      }

     }




<div id="divPageDlgContainer">
                        <div id="divEditPage" style="display: none">
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnPage" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phrPage" runat="server">
                                        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    *Current Page:
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCurrentPage" Columns="40" MaxLength="50" runat="server" />
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCurrentPage" runat="server" EnableClientScript="false"
                                                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required." ControlToValidate="txtCurrentPage"
                                                        ForeColor="Red" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    *Previous Page:
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPreviousPage" Columns="40" MaxLength="50" runat="server" />
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPreviousPage" runat="server" EnableClientScript="false"
                                                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required." ControlToValidate="txtPreviousPage"
                                                        ForeColor="Red" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    *Next Page:
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNextPage" Columns="40" MaxLength="50" runat="server" />
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNextPage" runat="server" EnableClientScript="false"
                                                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required." ControlToValidate="txtNextPage" ForeColor="Red" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2" align="right">
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSavePage" OnClick="btnSavePage_Click" Text="Save" runat="server" />
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancelPage" OnClick="btnCancelPage_Click" OnClientClick="closeDialog('#divEditPeriod')"
                                                        CausesValidation="false" Text="Cancel" runat="server" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </div>
                    </div>


<div id="divEditPeriodDlgContainer">
                    <div id="divEditPeriod" style="display: none">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlEditPeriod" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phrEditPeriod" runat="server">
                                    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                *Start Date:
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" Columns="40" MaxLength="50" runat="server" />
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvStartDate" runat="server" EnableClientScript="false"
                                                    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required." ControlToValidate="txtStartDate" ForeColor="Red" />
                                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revStartDate" runat="server" EnableClientScript="false"
                                                    ControlToValidate="txtStartDate" ValidationExpression="(([1-9]|1[012])[- /.]([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d)|((1[012]|0[1-9])(3[01]|2\d|1\d|0[1-9])(19|20)\d\d)|((1[012]|0[1-9])[- /.](3[01]|2\d|1\d|0[1-9])[- /.](19|20)\d\d)"
                                                    ErrorMessage="Not a valid Date." Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                *End Date:
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" Columns="40" MaxLength="50" runat="server" />
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEndDate" runat="server" EnableClientScript="false"
                                                    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required." ControlToValidate="txtEndDate" ForeColor="Red" />
                                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEndDate" runat="server" EnableClientScript="false"
                                                    ControlToValidate="txtEndDate" ValidationExpression="(([1-9]|1[012])[- /.]([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d)|((1[012]|0[1-9])(3[01]|2\d|1\d|0[1-9])(19|20)\d\d)|((1[012]|0[1-9])[- /.](3[01]|2\d|1\d|0[1-9])[- /.](19|20)\d\d)"
                                                    ErrorMessage="Not a valid Date." Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" align="right">
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSavePeriod_Click" Text="Save" runat="server" />
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" OnClick="btnCancelPeriod_Click" OnClientClick="closeDialog('#divEditPeriod')"
                                                    CausesValidation="false" Text="Cancel" runat="server" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </asp:PlaceHolder>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: what happends if you remove the "modal: true"-tag ? Or set it to "modal: faslse"? I think only one modal box is allowed

Comment: I changed it to modal: false and still the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="divPageDlgContainer">
```

should be

```
 <div id="divEditPageDlgContainer">
```

?